# Jade: How to extend base-templates based on value of a variable

Tags: express, pug, multiple-inheritance, template-engine, extends

I have two "master-templates" called `ios.jade` and `android.jade` plus multiple "child-templates" that should extend either `ios.jade` or `android.jade` based on the value of a variable. Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do this yet.

Something like the following came to my mind, but it doesn't work:

```
if (locals.os === "android")
  extends android
else
  extends ios
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to dynamically decide which "child-template" to include within the "master-template". Let's asume my "master-template" looks something like this (saved as `main.jade`):

```
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf8')
    base(href='/')
    title My super cool website
body
  if(locals.os === "android")
    include android
  else
    include ios
```

My other files are `android.jade`:

```
p android
```

...and `ios.jade`:

```
p ios
```

Now just render the "master-template" on your Node.js-Express server and see the magic happen (remember that the code below isn't complete, you need to setup the server first):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('main', {locals:{os: 'android'}});
});
```

Comment: This allows a given layout to render different childs based on a variable. That's already possible with template inheritance (and much simpler).